# Need another way to say "Here's to...."

Tags: word-choice

What is another way to say "here's to...." I am trying to reword, "Here's to a great 2nd year building our school." and don't want to use the "cheers" reference.

Comment: I can't guess either why you'd want such a thing - like, why re-invent the wheel? -or why that kind of style choice could belong here… nor even, what 'the "cheers" reference' means…

Did you know, there are any number of books or sites dedicated to writing speeches?

Comment: "Let's hear it for ..."

Answer (score 0):

> I'm/We're Looking forward to a great 2nd year...

It's not exactly the same, but close.

Answer (score 0):

> I [would like to] wish you/everyone/us all a...